# how to represent data (which chart is the best ?)

Tags: graphing-functions

I have data in tens of thousands such that it has two fields - time and stock rate. The time field is a field which is always increasing and is non repeating, While the stock rate always varies between 23 and 26. So, for the time column I have twenty thousand distinct values while for stock rate I would have just 30 values possible.

So my question is how to represent this data. what i can think now is that that the line chart ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_chart ) is the best way. So, is it ?

Comment: It depends what you are trying to use the data for.  I'm curious why you say there are only 30 values possible.  Are we taking tenths here?

Comment: Yes, so it would be like 23.1, 23.2 .... 25.9

Comment: So, at each time $t$ you would have multiple values? Are they related? Do they represent the same stock? Does the average matter? There are a lot of questions and the context is not clear.